# Are “zu-” and “ein-” special prefixes widely used to form new verbs?

Tags: verb, prefix

Are ***zu-*** and ***ein-*** special prefixes widely used to form new verbs in German language? Like the following two examples:

> **schlafen** (to sleep)
>   ein**schlafen** (to fall sleep)
>
> **hören** (to hear)
>   zu**hören** (to listen)

Are there any similar prefixes used in the same manner as above?

Comment: "ver-"; and this works for *schlafen* and *hören* :)

Comment: @Em1 I love 'ver-' as a prefix. If anything, it seems to be the most consistent prefix ever used except maybe 'un-' in the sense that I can mostly understand the meaning conveyed as well as the fact that I can guess words which turn out to be quite similar to real words.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Prefixation is a common way to change or further precise verb meanings.

According to this [nice summary at Canoon.net](http://www.canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-V/V-To-V/Praefig.html?lang=en) we have

- **separable prefixes:** verb and prefix are separated on inflection.
  *ab, an, auf, aus, bei, dar, ein, fehl, für, inne, los, nach, rück, vor, wieder, zu, zurecht, zwischen*
- **inseparable prefixes:** verb and prefix are not separated.
  *be, ent, er, ge, hinter, miss, ver, zer*
- **inseparable and separable prefixes:** both separation, and inseparable verbs exist from the same prefix.
  *durch, über, um, unter, wider*
- **foreign prefixes:** non-German prefixes used on verbs ending with "-ieren".
  *ab, ad, ante, co, de/des, dis, en, ex, in, inter, intro, kon, konter, kontra, per, post, prä, pro, re, retro, sub, trans, zirkum*

Each of these prefixes link to further explanations and usage examples at Canoo.net.

For the examples in question we can read there that **[zu-](http://www.canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-V/Praefixe/zu.html?lang=en)** is used to indicate a closing action or a direction given. The latter would be the case with *"zuhören"* where the directions is listening **to** somebody.

The prefix **[ein-](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=ein-&submit_button=Suche&view=1)** is used in a great variety of meanings, often used for a direction from the outside to the inside in the wider sense, a change of direction, or a change of state (i.e. used in *einschlafen* where the sate changes from wake to sleep), and many more.

A useful source is the [DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/) where we can search for prefixes by adding a hyphen to the prefix in the sarch field.

Answer (score 6):

There are a lot of such prefixes: `ein-`, `zu-`, `aus-`, `er-`, `zer-`, `ent-`, `ver-`, `vor-`, `nach-`, `gegen-`, `durch-`, `weiter-`, `über-`, `unter-`, `auf-`, `ge-`, `herein-`, `heraus-`, `hinein-`, `hinaus-`, `weg-` and others. There is a certain logic behind them, however you need to learn which combinations are possible.

E.g. for `schlafen` you have `einschlafen`, `ausschlafen`, `entschlafen`, `verschlafen`, `weiterschlafen`, `durchschlafen` and - not so common - `vorschlafen` and `wegschlafen` (more often `wegdämmern` or `wegdösen`).

For `hören` the combinations `zuhören`, `verhören` (two meanings), `überhören`, `aufhören`, `gehören`, `hereinhören`, `hineinhören`, `etwas heraushören` and `weghören` are possible (and probably some more).